# Linux Container - windows authenticatio issue

Tags: linux, security, docker, window

I got a Docker environment that contain Linux Containers,
I am running on one of those pods a program that try to access a windows server under a secure domain(my own),
How can i tell the container to run from a specific user , or vice versa how can i allow access to my Docker environment to my server?

I prefer the first option if possible.

Comment: Not sure I inderstand correctly your question : do you mean you want to build your container such as the application (within the container) run with a specific user? In such case, you just have to "RUN useradd -m youruser" then "RUN youruser" from within the Dockerfile (and before the CMD line) and manage the permissions the same way. If your problem is about how to access your windows server from whatever-user is the active user, you may have to provide the authentification in you CMD... maybe if you show a Dockerfile this would be easier for us to help

Comment: Hey Marvin,
Let me clarify my query (apologize for not being clear).
I am running an application i wrote in .net , That tries to connect to a Windows server and being blocked by Windows authentication , after doing some research i found out the solution is probably not "code" based but in the docker configuration.
My thought process was that maybe i can run the program from my system admin username and password , but now that i think about it its still do not grantee it will be able to access windows server from the Linux system.
I am out of work now so i will add the file later